# How can measure coherence of a coherent stare?

Tags: measurement

Coherent states are interest of many researchers.

Is there any measurement to measure the amount of coherence of a state?

What is name of the measure? And is there a simple article that its writer used it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are too many! Look up Mandel Q parameter, degree of coherence $g(2)$, negativity of the Glauber $P$ function, negativity of the Wigner function... I've probably even invented some myself.

For finite dimensional systems, coherence is given by the off-diagonal elements of the density matrix, but that depends on the basis you choose, leading to different definitions of coherence.

People have studied coherence as a resource, e.g., [here](https://doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.89.041003) and [here](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.116.120404), and even debated whether there really is coherence in coherent states, e.g., [here](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.55.3195) and [here](https://doi.org/10.1142/S0219749906001591)